# How come my correlation table has a opposite result from my growth curve model?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, growth-mixture-model

I have a three level model, level 1 is time points of measurements, level 2 is measurement day, and level 3 is participant, when I run correlation to understand within-person (between day), the correlation is positively significant, however, if I run a multilevel analysis following growth curve model, the results is negative significant, how come this is possible? Did I do something wrong? Any recommendation to understand this result

The opposite result between two analysis, I expect to have similar result that both negative or both positive

Comment: Hi KathyCatty and welcome to CV! To properly answer your question, it may be useful to _show_ the results of the analyses you have performed.